# Pulling .NET Dynamic Data by First Letter only

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I have a long list of dynamic data being generated on a jquery mobile site. I'd like to have this data be separated by alphabet list bars, much like the directory organization of a phone by first letter.

Another option would simply be to only call the data by first letter. For example, I select the letter "A", and all the data that starts with "A" displays.

I am calling names via ASP.NET.vb repeated method with: `<%# Eval("Name")%>`

That code of course pulls all names. How can I narrow it down to specific letter starts? I am new to ASP and ASP.NET; therefore, I'm not quite sure where to start or what terminology to start researching. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Call the first letter within the query of the WHERE.