# jQuery Mobile data-filter to read dynamic content

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to implement a search bar to filter dynamic content in jQuery mobile by first letter. I want to implement data-filter like this: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/lists/docs-lists.html#../../docs/lists/lists-search-inset.html

Super easy to do. However, I have a minor problem throwing me off. All my content is dynamic. Each record being read is a new list. Because data-filters are used for lists, I have a search bar above each record. My .NET code for my output looks like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater27" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource27">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                           <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
                                <li class="list-head"><strong><%# Eval("Name")%></strong></li>
                                <li class="list-body"><a href="mailto:<%# Eval("Email")%>"><%# Eval("GrEmail")%></a></li>
                                <li class="list-body"><%# Eval("Telephone")%></li>
                            </ul>
                   </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

Because I am using a Repeater to list my dynamic content, it too is repeating my filter. I have tried moving the filter outside of my repeated region, and this doesn't work. In addition, the filter has to be attached to the list it is reading to work anyway.

Is there a work around from using a repeater in .NET? 
Or is there a workaround for filters?
Can data-filter work for collapsible-sets?

I'm open to any and all suggestions. I greatly appreciate any insight you may have to offer. This has got to be a common problem with implementing dynamic content on a site. I'm wondering how the jQuery mobile documentation did this??

Thoughts?

Comment: This post is sort of related to my older one: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856909/pulling-net-dynamic-data-by-first-letter-only); however, I like the data-filter direction...

Answer (score 1):

Only Li should be repeated !! :)

change it with

`

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater27" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource27">
                    <ItemTemplate>

                                <li class="list-head"><strong><%# Eval("Name")%></strong></li>
                                <li class="list-body"><a href="mailto:<%# Eval("Email")%>"><%# Eval("GrEmail")%></a></li>
                                <li class="list-body"><%# Eval("Telephone")%></li>

                   </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
 </ul>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

The  should be outside of the repeater. The remaining dynamic content should then be within only one set of

tags.